Right maximal ideals in skew-Laurent rings over division Rings
Let $R$ be a Noetherian domain, and let $D$ denote its division ring. Define $S = D_q[x_1^{\pm 1}, x_2^{\pm 1}]$ as an iterated skew-Laurent polynomial ring with the relation $x_1 x_2 = q x_2 x_1$. Is there a right maximal ideal $I$ of $S$ such that the $R_q[x_1^{\pm 1}, x_2^{\pm 1}]$-module $R_q[x_1^{\pm 1}, x_2^{\pm 1}] / I^c$ is finitely generated over $R_q[x_1^{\pm 1}, x_2^{\pm 1}]$, where $I^c$ is the contraction of $I$ in $R_q[x_1^{\pm 1}, x_2^{\pm 1}]$?
Additionally, is $(y_1 y_2 + 1) S$ a right maximal ideal of $S$?
